# Do I need to get a transit visa for a layover at a Canadian airport?

Tags: air-travel, visas, transit, filipino-citizens, yyz

I am a Philippine passport holder and I'm planning to travel to St Vincent and the Grenadines this month. Do I need to get a transit visa during my layover at Toronto and Port of Spain?

Comment: What is YYZ? Toronto Pearson International Airport?

Comment: yes..Toronto Pearson International Airport.

Answer (score 5):

You need a Canadian visa (unless you have a US visa and you travel to/from the USA). I assume you are a resident of Philippines. Here are relevant references:

From Timatic:

> National Philippines (PH)       /Transit Canada (CA) Destination St.
>   Vincent and the Grenadines (VC) ALSO CHECK DESTINATION INFORMATION
>   BELOW
>
> Canada (CA)
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   - ONLY IF ALL CONDITIONS BELOW ARE MET-
>
> Visa required, except for Nationals of Philippines holding
>
> confirmed onward tickets transiting For details, click here on the
>   same calendar day, (SEE NOTE 43594) (SEE NOTE 43595) provided:
>   - travelling to/from the USA; and
>   - holding a valid US visa. (SEE NOTE 39687)
>       NOTE 43594: Facility available if transiting through
>
> Toronto Pearson International (YYZ) AND arriving on
>
> aircraft operated by Air Canada or Jazz Air (insertion of
>
> SSR TWOV in PNR is required). Note: codeshare flight    numbers of
>   these carriers operated by another carrier are    not included.
>   Connecting flight can be with any carrier.
>
> ```
> NOTE 43595: Facility available if transiting through
> ```
>
> Vancouver (YVR) AND arriving on aircraft operated by Air    Canada
>   or Jazz Air (insertion of SSR TWOV in PNR is
>
> required), or Air China, Cathay Pacific, China Airlines or
>   Philippine Airlines. Note: codeshare flight numbers of    these
>   carriers operated by another carrier are not    included. Connecting
>   flight can be with any carrier.
>
> ```
> NOTE 39687: If holding an expired US visa    For details, click here
> ```
>
> - The YVR In-Transit Pre-Clearance Facility (ITPCF) which   handles international passengers travelling to USA, is open
>
> from 04:30-20:30 hours; the YVR facility that processes   passengers
>   arriving from USA and continuing internationally,
>
> is open 24 hours.   The YYZ ITPCF, which handles international
>   passengers
>
> travelling to USA, is open from 04:30-21:00 hours; the YYZ
>   facility that processes passengers arriving from USA and   continuing
>   internationally, is open 24 hours.
>
> Additional Information:
>
> - Visitors are required to hold proof of sufficient funds to   cover their stay and documents required for their next   destination.
>
> Warning:
>   - Visitors not holding return/onward ticket could be refused
>
> entry.

From Air Canada http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/twov-tsv/it-iiv-eng.html :

> Nationals from the following countries qualify for the Transit Without
>   Visa (TWOV) program:
>
> ```
> Indonesia
> Thailand
> Taiwan (see notice below)
> the Philippines
> ```

...

> **All nationals who qualify for the TWOV program must also meet these conditions:**
>
> ```
> They hold a valid passport issued by an approved country (listed above);
> They hold a valid U.S. visa;
> They travel to Canada on an approved airline; and
> They transit through an approved Canadian airport.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I guess so, since Philippines isn't visa exempt.

http://gocanada.about.com/od/canadatravelplanner/qt/transit_visa_canada.htm

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091024173618AALX0ta